# The array does not show the information echo

Tags: php

No I'm doing wrong, I am modifying a system created by someone else but I can not show the information ... This is the code ...

```
$db = DB::getInstance();
$id = 1;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", array($id));
$x = $query->results();
echo $x;
```

The error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in...`

Comment: You cannot `echo` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r($x)` instead of `echo $x`
echo is used to print string and numbers but could not print array,
you may use `var_dump` too ... actually `var_dump` is used to print objects

Comment: Get "Array ( )" but not the list of all IDs.

Comment: In the table "users" there is a column "username" I want to list all user names ...

Comment: then what is the result of current query

Comment: It shows nothing!

Comment: so  you want enlist usernames right

Comment: i think it will not show you more than one record if it exists in database.... did you check the result in respective RDBMS firing direct query

Comment: There are 2 records in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump (instead of echo) if the return value is an object. For example:

```
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: In the table "users" there is a column "username" I want to list all user names ...

Comment: Update this for all users

$db = DB::getInstance();
$id = 1;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$x = $query->results();

for ($i=0;$i<count($x); $i++){
        echo $x[$i]."<br/>";
    }

Answer (score 0):

use FOR :

```
$db = DB::getInstance();
$id = 1;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", array($id));
$x = $query->results();

for ($i=0;$i<count($x); $i++){
        echo $x[$i]."<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: It shows nothing!

Comment: Sure that the connection is correct? Other queries work?

Comment: @GePraxa: use `var_dump` to debug your data instead of `echo`. BTW, you cannot echo *array*